# Choose a specific geometry column of a Spatial View in a Microsoft database to plot feature points in ArcMap

Tags: arcmap, sql-server, arccatalog, spatial-view

I have created a Spatial View in a Microsoft SQL database (SQL Server Manamgement Studio v18.4), i.e. a View with spatial columns. This View contains the two following point geometry columns for two different coordinate systems (CH1903/LV03 [EPSG 21781] and CH1903+/LV95 [EPSG 2056] respectively):

1. `geometry::Point(X1, Y1, 21781) AS GEOM_1`
2. `geometry::Point(X2, Y2, 2056) AS GEOM_2`

In ArcCatalog, this View is recognized as a Spatial View, i.e. at least one of the spatial columns is recognized as such by ArcCatalog. However, when drag-and-pull this View from ArcCatalog into the Data Frame of ArcMap 10.7, I can not choose which one of these two geometry columns is used to plot the points. ArcMap automatically takes the geometry column with CH1903/LV03 [EPSG 21781] coordinates. How can I enforce the other geometry column to be used to plot the points?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ArcMap does not support multiple spatial columns in a feature class.  You can create two separate views, each with a different spatial column, and add them to ArcMap as two feature classes.